# Second differences in polynomials of degree 2 (Gelfand/Shen, Algebra. Chapter 38)

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Problem 156 (page 72):

> $$ P(x)=x^2-x-4 $$
>
> Prove that the second differences are not a coincidence and that they
>   repeat for all $ x\geq 0 $.

Problem 157 (page 73):

> Prove that for any polynomial of degree 2 all second differences are equal.

I saw while researching that we can represent the three series (P(x), the first difference and the second difference) using the first result of each as a variable. Then using these first three variables, we can recreate all or each series. When I do this, I see that it is not "coincidence" but I cannot find a way to prove it.

I've seen online that this can be proved with Calculus but I don't believe that Calculus is a pre-requisite to the book: on the contrary, I rather think that it is written to be worked through using "basic algebra".

Answer (score 0):

You might find it useful to show that the difference of a constant term $a-a=0$ is zero, the difference of a first degree term $a(x+1)-ax=a$ is constant, and the difference of a quadratic term $a(x+1)^2-ax^2=2ax+a$ is linear.

Differencing is a linear operation which reduces the degree by $1$. So applying it twice reduces the degree by $2$ and in the quadratic case gives you a constant.

Sometimes the differencing operation is easier to calculate using the identities:

$x-(x-1)=1$

$(x+1)x-x(x-1)=2x$

$(x+2)(x+1)x-(x+1)x(x-1)=3(x+1)x$

$(x+3)(x+2)(x+1)x-(x+2)(x+1)x(x-1)=4(x+2)(x+1)x$

The difference at each stage is a term of the same kind, but of lower order. So one begins by writing the initial expression as a sum of these factorial-type terms.

If we let $f_n(x)=(x+n-1)(x+n-2)\dots x$, so that $n$ is the order of each term, then we have $f_n(x)-f_n(x-1)=nf_{n-1}(x)$

Often it is convenient to use $g_n(x)=\cfrac{f_n(x)}{n!}$ so that $g_n(x)-g_n(x-1)=g_{n-1}(x)$